# How to use vue3 input component with vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm a newbie with vuejs. I'm trying to use the input component with vee-validate and I got this example [example link](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-text-input-with-vee-validate-v4-forked-fnpvn) as an example that works great but I'm unable to create a v-model with this example. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useForm` and `useField` which are two custom composition API in vee-validate. I write an [example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-text-input-with-vee-validate-v4-forked-xzcn9) which is what you want.

For further details please read this two documentation:

[useField API reference](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-field)

[useForm API reference](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-form)